# How can I train in MLP backpropagation if training class labels are given with their confidence rate?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation

How can I make use of the information that shows confidence of that training instance? i.e. We have an extra information for training set about the confidence of class labels.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd try would be to incorporate the confidence into the objective function by weighting each example by the confidence, i.e., rather than minimizing 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \ell\left(y_i, \hat{y}_i\right)
$$
for some loss function $\ell$ (squared error, cross entropy, etc), minimize
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\cdot\ell\left(y_i, \hat{y}_i\right)
$$
where I've assumed $c_i \in [0, 1]$ is the confidence of each label, $y_i$ is the $i^\text{th}$ label and $\hat{y}_i$ is the output of the ANN.

I don't have a reference for this approach for your particular problem, but it was the first thing that popped to mind and seems sensible. It is similar to the approach one might take when constructing a cost-sensitive learner, see [Cost-sensitive learning by cost-proportionate example weighting](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.5.9780&rep=rep1&type=pdf).